# $a, b, c$ form a geometric sequence and $\log_c a, \log_ b c, \log_a b$ form an arithmetic sequence.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

The common difference of the arithmetic sequence can be expressed as $\frac mn$, where $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime positive integers. Find $m+n.$

So far, I rearranged the sequences to be

1: $a$, $ar$, $ar^2$

2: $\log_c a, \log_c a + d, \log_c a + 2d$

I plugged in a, ar and ar^2 to the corresponding a, b, and c in the log sequence.

Then, I don't know what to do!

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a little more information. Expand on what you're asking and explain what you have tried and what you don't know.

Comment: This is all this the problem gives. I rewrote the equations to be a->ar->ar^2 and log base c a-> log base c a+d -> log base c a +2d. Then I'm stuck!

Comment: Do you mind editing your question by adding in your work so far?

Comment: I have included it!

Comment: Hint: $\displaystyle\,
\log_c{a}=\frac{\log(a)}{\log(c)}=\frac{\log(a)}{\log(ar^2)}=\frac{\log(a)}{\log(a)+ 2 \log(|r|)}\,$.

Comment: Hmm, @dxiv. I think I know where this might go. Would I change all the corresponding logs with the a, ar and ar^2 plugged in to the fraction form, add them up to be equal to 3 * log base ar^2 a + 3d?

Comment: You can eliminate $d$ by observing that $a+c=2b$ in any arithmetic sequence. (Because $d=b-a=c-b$.)

Comment: @ShadyAF Let the GP be $\,b/r, b, b\cdot r\,$ and let $\,u=\log b, v=\log r\,$, then $\,\log_c a=\dfrac{u-v}{u+v}\,$. Calculate the other two $\log$ values, then apply the condition for AP and see what you get in terms of $u,v$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

We have to constrain that,  $a,b,c$ are all positive numbers which do not equal $1$. According to the assumption conditions, we have $$b^2=ac,\tag1$$and$$2\log_b c=\log_a b+\log_c a.\tag2$$
From $(1)$, $b=\sqrt{ac}$. Put it into $(2)$ and apply the base-changing formula.  Thus, $$\frac{4\ln c}{\ln a +\ln c}=\frac{\ln a+\ln c}{2\ln a}+\frac{\ln a}{\ln c}.\tag3$$Denote $t=\dfrac{\ln a}{\ln c}.$ Then,we can obtain the equation$$2t^3+3t^2-6t+1=(t-1)(2t^2+5t-1)=0.\tag4$$
By solving it,we have the roots $$t_1=1,t_2=\frac{-5-\sqrt{33}}{4},t_3=\frac{-5+\sqrt{33}}{4}.$$ On the other hand,let the common difference be $d$,then $$d=\log_c-\log_c a=\frac{\ln c}{\ln b}-\frac{\ln a}{\ln c}=\frac{2-t^2-t}{t+1}\tag5.$$

- If $t=t_1=1$, then $d=0$. In this case, $a=b=c$,which is trivial;
- If $t=t_2$ or $t_3$, then $t^2=\dfrac{1-5t}{2}$.Thus, $d=\dfrac{2-t^2-t}{t+1}=\dfrac{3(t+1)}{2(t+1)}=\dfrac{3}{2}$.

Summing up the above, it follows that $d=0$ or $d=\dfrac{3}{2}.$ We are done.

Comment: Hey, I don't understand where you went on your 5th equation while trying to find d.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We have $a>0$, $b>0,$ $c>0$, $a\neq1$, $b\neq1$ and $c\neq1$.

Also, $b^2=ac$ and
$$2\log_bc=\log_ca+\log_ab$$ or
$$2\log_{\sqrt{ac}}c=\log_ca+\log_a\sqrt{ac}$$ or

$$4\log_{ac}c=\log_ca+\frac{1}{2}\log_aac$$ or
$$\frac{8}{1+\log_ca}=2\log_ca+1+\frac{1}{\log_ca},$$ which gives
$$\log_ca\in\left\{1,\frac{-5-\sqrt{33}}{4},\frac{-5+\sqrt{33}}{4}\right\}.$$
Now, can you choose the answer?